# Using elsarticle how can I write the Manuscript and Supplementary / Supporting Information in one file? OR How to create a mid-document titlepage?

Tags: elsarticle

Often when writing papers it would be beneficial to write the main paper and the supporting information in one file to make use of referencing possibilities of LaTeX.

This however does require a second front matter in the middle at the beginning of the appendix/supporting information.

How to accomplish this for the elsarcticle class?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out a bit the hacky way by skimming through the .cls file. It works for my purposes. Just write the paper as normal, when you are coming to the appendix you need to include a bunch of commands to reprint a slightly modified title.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to demonstration
% your paper goes here
% ...

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{library}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% APPENDIX %%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\appendix
%\nolinenumbers % if you are using lineo package
\newpage
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{s\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}

% most counters defined by elsarticle (just in case), important here is affn
% \setcounter{ead}{0}
% \setcounter{tnote}{0}
% \setcounter{fnote}{0}
% \setcounter{cnote}{0}
% \setcounter{author}{0}
\setcounter{affn}{0}
\resetTitleCounters

% Remove the title so we can fill a new one in
\makeatletter
\let\@title\@empty
\makeatother

\title{Supplementary Data for: The Paper title again}

% I'm using the abstract environment to put a table of contents
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\global\setbox\absbox=\vbox\bgroup
  \hsize=\textwidth\def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \noindent\unskip\textbf{Contents}
 \par\medskip\noindent\unskip}
 {\egroup}

% here we modify the footnote on the title page to reflect that these are supporting info
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
     \let\@oddhead\@empty
     \let\@evenhead\@empty
     \def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape
        Supplementary Data for \ifx\@journal\@empty Elsevier
       \else\@journal\fi\hfill\today}%
     \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

% making the new TOC for the SI
\startlist{toc}
\begin{abstract}
\vspace{-48pt}
\printlist{toc}{}{\section*{}}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section*{}
\parindent0pt
% your content starts here
\section{Demonstration of something in more detail}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Another thing I would like to show}
\lipsum[4-8]
\section{More stuff}
\lipsum[9-10]

\end{document}
```

Then mid document you get a nice title page for your supporting info and you can just keep on putting stuff and using all the cross-referencing you want. This is how it looks like:
[image]